# how can I format the x axis such that I can skip over values using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to format my xticks such that there aren't any gaps as I currently have in the plot below. I only want to have the points in the xaxis that are in my data.

My x axis points are below and that's all I want and:

```
[128, 132, 136, 140, 149, 153, 157, 161, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124]
```

how can I define my formatter?

[image: plot1]

Comment: You could try to remap your `x` from `[36,40,44...]` to `[1,2,3,...]`, then change the labels to the original `[36,40,44,...]`

Comment: Try use `xticks`. You can se it in the manual

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set data
x = [36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132,  136,  140, 149,  153, 157, 161]
y = [15.25, 15, 15.1, 14.9, 14.25, 14.1, 14, 13.9, 13.8, 14.2, 14.75, 14.8, 15.4, 15.45, 15.5, 15.25, 15.6, 15.2, 15.3, 15.25, 15.5, 15.2, 15.25]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 4), dpi=80)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x) # << HERE

plt.show()
```

[image]